# 3d flip + slick.js is flipping automatically after first rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some kind of bug with my carousel + 3d flipping in CSS3. When I click through the carousel and flip the button, the first slide would automatically flip/flop after the whole rotation.

Here's a [screencast of what I mean.](http://www.screencast.com/t/6Z6IQxI1)

and [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/umdps02p/)

```
var init = function() {
  var flippers = document.getElementsByClassName("flip");

    for(i = 0; i < flippers.length; i++){
        flippers[i].addEventListener( 'click', function(){
            var cardID = this.getAttribute('data-targetid');;
            var card = document.getElementById(cardID);
            card.toggleClassName('flipped');
  }, false);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Removing `z-index: 2` from `.front` fixes it for me</strike>

Great question by the way. Screencast, jsfiddle, code sample... beautiful!

Add this to the CSS in the fiddle:

```
.slick-cloned {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then you will see that before it "flashes" from the front to back, it's actually that the cloned slide in visible, and is then removed.

Comment: Hi @elzi - thanks but removing z-index didn't worked. I also changed it to z-index: 0 with no luck.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you're right. I was getting intermittent success/behavior. View my updated answer - I don't have a fix yet, but I found out what's doing it.

Comment: nice spot there elzi. So it's cloning the first slide. I tried hiding the clone, it will solve the main problem but will another: appearing and disappearing slide.

Comment: You could fix it by modifying the slick JS to set an array of which card were 'flipped', and use that to automatically add that class to the `slick-cloned` element on each slide move.

Ooooor you could settle and do `infinite: false` in the slick options...

Comment: The `infinite: false` works for now. Hope this will be enough for my company's requirement. Thanks elzi!

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with this in Safari. Other wise this was great help for an issue I was looking into the same thing.
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/

**backface-visibility:**
Firefox 10+ and IE 10+ support backface-visibility with no prefix. Opera (post Blink, 15+), Chrome, Safari, iOS, and Android all need -webkit-backface-visibility.